# How to access hosts in a different subnet?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, routing

A Windows 2008 server of mine is 192.168.1.1

A server I need to access from the first server is 192.168.2.1 in the same physical network.

How do I access it?

Can I define a second TCP/IP interface over the same NIC or something?

Comment: what is the subnet mask?

Comment: 255.255.255.0 of course, @Rex

Comment: it's not of course - many people change the mask to meet their needs. You could change the mask and make them part of the same network. what do you mean by same physical network? Are they connected to the same switch? If so, you could add a 2nd IP address on the same interface to the 2nd network.

Comment: This question lacks the detail needed to provide a proper answer.

Comment: "Are they connected to the same switch?" - Yes. "If so, you could add a 2nd IP address on the same interface to the 2nd network." - How?

Comment: How the heck is it not a real question? Absolutely real and practical.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to @Rex for the idea, I have found the solution myself:

[image]

I never knew I can actually assign more than one IP address to a single network interface in Windows.

Comment: If this actually worked, then your network has serious problems that go far beyond this immediate issue.

Comment: I've just retaken the network from another administrator. What would you suggest? Setting up VLANs? The whole building routing is done by a single LinkSys WRT160NV3 SOHO router and the management is hardly going to let me change this, @MichaelHampton